# Problems connecting to database on remotesql.com

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have been using [remotemysql.com](https://remotemysql.com) as a remote database and have had issues attempting to log in since 1.5 days ago.

I'm getting `SQL connection error: connect ECONNREFUSED` in my app and `mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory` when trying to login via browser.

In fact, the website used to link to https://remotemysql.com/phpmyadmin/index.php to log into the database when clicking `phpMyAdmin` but the link is different now (the login details still fail to work).

I can't find any information about this, did they close down the database or something?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I am having exactly the same issue. Something has happened to the website that has made it go down. For example, if you go to the [login](https://remotemysql.com/login.php) page, it says: `Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory`. I guess we need to wait for remotemysql to sort themselves out then this will be fixed.

I tried looking for any contact details but there aren't any as far as I'm aware, so I'm not exactly hopeful.

Comment: Ah that's a shame. Have you found an alternative to use?

Comment: I had a small explore and couldn't find anything for my needs. However, https://freedb.tech/ offers something similar which you may be able to use.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it works ok for my usecase. I checked remotesql.com and it's back again, though.